# Infer "shapes", or infer analogous relations in Word2Vec

Tags: gensim, word2vec

Gensim Word2Vec offers a system for inferring analogous relationships, that is, with the "same shape" as those already found?

Es:
Starting from **King, Queen**

I would like to get other couples with male / female gender.

In other word:
most_similar(positive=['king', X], negative=['queen']) -> Y

I would like to find as many xy pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in facility resembling what I think you're asking.

But, you are of course free to cycle through any number of candidate words (as `X`, or the other arguments to `most_similar()`), to see what top-neighbors are reported (candidate `Y` values) - perhaps applying some threshold of similarity.

Note the famous `man:king :: woman: _?_` is usually presented to a word2vec model in Gensim as `most_similar(positive=['king', 'woman'], negative=['man'])`, which sort of achieves `king - man + woman = _?_`. I'm not sure your alternate formulation, effectively `king - queen + X = Y` has an analogical meaning, for arbitrary `X` or responses `Y`.

And, note that `most_similar()` suppresses the reporting of any candidate wards that are already arguments to `positive` or `negative`. Often, the results of the 'artihmetic' are still closer to the input words than anything else - but that won't be reported, showing next-best words instead.

Comment: That's right, you got the question. Thanks for your help